# Snowflake scripting set variable in if statment

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake I trying to set a variable to different values depend on input to the procedure.

When I read about the if statment here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html

I can't figure out how to use the input type_name to set a new variable or overwrite the query variable if type_name have a specific value, any ideas?

```
create or replace procedure test_sp_dynamic(table_name varchar,type_name varchar)
returns table(X varchar)
language sql
as
$$
  declare
    tn varchar default :type_name;
    tn_2 varchar;
    res RESULTSET;
    query varchar default 'SELECT Y ' || :table_name || ' ORDER BY Y';
  begin
   
    res := (execute immediate :query);
    return table (res);
  end;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is vague. It is possible to overwrite the query defined in `DECLARE` block.

Test table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(Y VARCHAR, Z VARCHAR)
AS SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL SELECT 10,20;
```

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure test_sp_dynamic(table_name varchar,type_name varchar)
returns table(X varchar)
language sql
as
$$
declare
    res RESULTSET;
    query VARCHAR;
begin
    if (:type_name = 'some_value') then
        query := 'SELECT Z FROM ' || :table_name || ' ORDER BY Z';
    else
        query := 'SELECT Y FROM ' || :table_name || ' ORDER BY Y';
    end if;
   
    res := (execute immediate :query);
    return table(res);
end;
$$
;

CALL test_sp_dynamic('t', 'some_value');
-- X
-- 2
-- 20

CALL test_sp_dynamic('t', 'else');
-- X
-- 1
-- 10
```